# .NET MAUI MVVM: Capturing Updated Values in ViewModel with ReturnCommand on Entry Field Exit

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit, .net-maui.shell

I am developing an application in .NET MAUI using the MVVM pattern . My goal is to perform calculations automatically when the user exits an Entry field, without the need for an additional button press. To achieve this, I have bound the ReturnCommand of each Entry to a command in my ViewModel, but I am not receiving the updated value of the bound property in the command when the user changes fields.

Here is my implementation:

```
<Entry Placeholder="Cantidad Cajas"
       Text="{Binding NumberBoxBuy, Mode=TwoWay}"
       ReturnCommand="{Binding EntryCompletedCommand}"
       ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"/>
```

My viewModels

```
[ObservableProperty] 
public int numberBoxBuy;

[RelayCommand]
private async Task EntryCompleted()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Number entered: {NumberBoxBuy}");
}
```

Comment: I'd guess the `ReturnCommand` is simply firing before the value is updated

Comment: You binds the text of entry to a int property. Have you tried using ```string numberBoxBuy;``` or a valueconverter?

Comment: May I know if the issue has been resolved? Here is the official doc for [Value Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters?view=net-maui-8.0).